# node.js apn Failed to generate token

Tags: node.js, express, apple-push-notifications

As title, i use node-apn package to send push notification to iOS devices.

In my local machine (MacOS), i can send notification to device successfully, but when i deploy my codes to a CentOS server, i can't apnProvider object.

My Codes is:

```js
var apn = require('apn')
var path = require('path')

let options = {
  token: {
    key: path.resolve('/path/to/f8/keyfile'),
    keyId: 'myKeyId',
    teamId: "myTeamID"
  },
  production: false
};

var apnProvider = new apn.Provider(options);
```

I got this error, (i tried google about it but can't find a solution):

/root/buzzship/node.js/node_modules/apn/lib/credentials/token/prepare.js:45
      throw new VError(err, "Failed to generate token");
      ^
VError: Failed to generate token: error:0906D064:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad base64 decode
    at prepareToken (/root/buzzship/node.js/node_modules/apn/lib/credentials/token/prepare.js:45:13)
    at config (/root/buzzship/node.js/node_modules/apn/lib/config.js:42:31)
    at new Client (/root/buzzship/node.js/node_modules/apn/lib/client.js:11:19)
    at EventEmitter.Provider (/root/buzzship/node.js/node_modules/apn/lib/provider.js:12:19)
    at Object. (/root/buzzship/node.js/index-api.js:128:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:393:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:508:3

Please tell me what i am wrong at, thank you.

Comment: Try updating your OpenSSL and Node versions

Comment: What is your CentOS version? Update your question with following outputs `cat /etc/redhat-release` and `node -p process.versions`

Comment: My CentOS version is 7.3.1611
- node -p process.versions output is 6.10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for suggestions, i solved this issue by upgrade node to version latest 7.10.0.